# Find bipartial subgraph such that mean square deviation of edge lengths is minimum

Tags: algorithms, graphs, bipartite-graph

Let there be graph $G = (V, \, E)$. $G$ has neither loops nor parallel arcs.

$V = A \cup B, \, A \neq \emptyset, \, B \neq \emptyset, A \cap B = \emptyset$

For simplicity's sake, let's consider $G$ is directed.

$\forall \ e \in E \ \, e.tail \in A, \, e.head \in B, \, e.length \in (\mathbb{Z} \cap [1, 100]) \cup -\infty \\
\forall \ a \in A, \, b \in B \ \ \exists! \ e \in E: e = (a, b)$

**The goal is** to develop an algorithm that finds a bipartite subgraph $G' = (V', \, E')$ such that:

1) $|\,E'\;|$ **is maximum**;
2) Under restriction 1), $\sum \limits_{e' \in E'} (e'.length - (\sum \limits_{e' \in E'} e'.length \; / \; |\,  E' \; |))^2 $ **is minimum possible**, where $| \, E' \; |$ is cardinality of $E'$.

For example, let graph $G$ be defined as following:
[image]

In this case, the correct solution is:
[image]

The algorithm should run in polynomial time.

Comment: Is the goal actually to find a matching? The graph you are starting with is already bipartite so any subgraph of it is also bipartite. In which case, just take the empty graph or the graph consisting of any one edge which has standard deviation $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The way to make $|E'|$ be maximum is to take all the edges, i.e., set $E'=E$.  Since your graph is already bipartite, this subgraph will be as well.  Then criterion 2 is irrelevant, as there is only one way to achieve the maximum for criterion 1.